# Different results with post-increment operator in for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, increment

In Javascript, I'm having trouble understanding why these two sets of code provide different results:

```
for (var i = 0, a = []; i++ < 9;) {a.push(i);}
```

After running this code, the variable `a` is the following: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`.

However, this code returns something else:

```
for (var i = 0, a = []; i < 9; i++) {a.push(i);}
```

Instead, the variable `a` is the following after running this code: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

So, the major question: **Why is this the case?**

Thanks for any answers that explain this difference.

Comment: In the first case, the increment happens before the push and after the check for < 9. Hence, you get numbers from 1 to 9. In the second code, the value of i is only incremented after the first run and the check for < 9 is done after the increment.

Comment: You can look at an explnation of the for loop at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 2):

It's just the order in which the `for` loop operations take place.  The three expressions are evaluated:

```
  for (before the loop starts;                   // initialization 
       before each iteration of the loop;        // loop condition
       at the end of each iteration of the loop) // loop increment
```

That makes your `i++` get run at different times relative to the loop body and explains the results you see.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this now.  Does this mean that what is returned by i++ is passed to the next condition, making the difference between ++i and i++ when it is in the increment area?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand that question.  Are you asking about the difference between the pre-increment and post-increment operators?

Comment: OK, let me explain.  Take a look at this example:  
`i=0;i++; i`  
It will always return 1, regardless of whether it is `i++` or `++i`.  However, for this code: `i=0; i++`, it will return 0.

Comment: Yes, all of that is expected.  I'm still not really sure what you're asking, though. `i` is `1` after both of those sequences, it's just that the post-increment operator returns the value before doing the increment.